# How to have DISPLAY 'automatically' set by Eclipse's remote debugging session?

Tags: ssh, display, eclipse

When I *ssh* to my target (Terasic DE10-Nano, a board with ARM A9 inside FPGA running Ubuntu 18.04 base) from my host (a laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64), the window created by the program I run on that target can be displayed on the host. That's because when I *ssh* to that target, the environment variable **DISPLAY** in the remote shell are always be automatically set to **localhost:N.0**, where **N** may be 10, 11, etc, by *ssh*.

However, when I use Eclipse on the host to remote-debug programs on the target, the window created by the debugged program can not be displayed on the host. Eclipse connects to the target using *ssh*, but the value of **DISPLAY** is not set and is blank (verified by: **echo $DISPLAY**). Once I set **DISPLAY** to **localhost:10.0** in Eclipse, this issue will be solved. 
(In case it helps, here is how I set it: In Eclipse Oxygen.3's *Debug Configuration* > *Main* > *Command to execute before application*, set this field to **export DISPLAY=localhost:N.0**. And it's also necessary to manually *ssh* to the target and make sure the **DISPLAY** in that remote shell is **localhost:N.0**)

I'm wondering whether it is possible, during such Eclipse remote-debugging session, **DISPLAY** can be set automatically? If yes, then neither setting it in *Debug Configuration* nor manually *ssh*ing to the target is required.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is that you can simply prepend the environment variable when launching eclipse:

```
DISPLAY=localhost:N.0; eclipse
```

You could then add an alias for this, for example:

```
alias eclipse-remote='DISPLAY=localhost:N.0; eclipse'
```

and put it in .bashrc (or .bash_aliases).  Make source you run `source .bashrc` for the change to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately it doesn't work in this way: setting the variable DISPLAY in host's shell.  DISPLAY need to be set in target's shell.